# Advantages of creating Python Toolbox over Custom Toolbox?

Tags: arcpy, arctoolbox, python-toolbox

I enjoy making different geoprocessing tools to practice Python and to become more familiar with the arcpy modules. I've just been using a Custom Toolbox and then importing the Python script and setting the parameters, but I'm wondering if I should be using a Python Toolbox instead.

Are there any distinct advantages of one Toolbox over the other?